# Emacs c-mode-hook runs when opening a php file

Tags: php, emacs, c-mode

I created a hook function to activate irony-mode when working with c files. However, when I open a php file, these hook is also executed.

Here is the code:

```
(defun my-company-irony ()
  (irony-mode)
  (unless (memq 'company-irony company-backends)
    (setq-local company-backends (cons 'company-irony company-backends))))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'my-company-irony)
```

Does anybody knows how to stop executing this hook on php files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `php-mode` inherits from `c-mode`, which I think means it will run `c-mode-hook`.  If you look at cc-mode.el, other C-like modes inherit from `prog-mode` instead of directly from `c-mode`, which is probably the Right Thing.  You should probably submit a bug to `php-mode`.

To fix it in the meantime, just wrap your code in a test for `c-mode`

```
(defun my-company-irony ()
  (when (eq major-mode 'c-mode)
    (irony-mode)
    (unless (memq 'company-irony company-backends)
      (setq-local company-backends (cons 'company-irony company-backends)))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I imagined that was the problem. In the meantime, your solution works for me.